# Group column items from SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, grouping

I have a series of listviews that are generated from data stored in an SQLite database on the phone. Lets say the table looks like this:

```
__________________________________________
|   ID   |     X    |    Y    |     Z    | 
|________|__________|_________|__________| 
|   1    |   ABC    |   123   |   B94    | 
|   2    |   ABC    |   234   |   C33    | 
|   3    |   DEF    |   567   |   N72    | 
|   4    |   DEF    |   789   |   K12    |  
|________|__________|_________|__________|...
```

I want to create a listview from column 'X', and when clicked, opens up the data in column 'Y' that's associated with it's row in a new listview. The tricky part is that I want to group the same items in each column together in their listview. In this example, the first listview would have only two items "ABC; DEF" and when "ABC" is clicked it will display "123; 234" items in the next listview.

Heres my code (Yes, I modified most of it from tutorials!):

**listviewactivity.java**

```
public class listviewactivity extends Activity {    
private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
 ListView listContent;   
 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.expenses);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();        

    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
    String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2};
    cursorAdapter =
     new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);    


}

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
 }
}
```

**SQLiteAdapter.java**

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {
public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Content1";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Content2";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT3 = "Content3"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT4 = "Content4"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT5 = "Content5"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT6 = "Content6"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT7 = "Content7"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT8 = "Content8";

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
 "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
 + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
 + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, "
 + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null,"  
 + KEY_CONTENT3 + " text not null, "
 + KEY_CONTENT4 + " text not null,"   
 + KEY_CONTENT5 + " text not null, "
 + KEY_CONTENT6 + " text not null,"   
 + KEY_CONTENT7 + " text not null,"  
 + KEY_CONTENT8 + " text not null);"; 

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context context;
public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){

 context = c;

} 

public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
 sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
 sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 return this; 

} 

public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
 sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
 sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 return this; 

}

public void close(){
sqLiteHelper.close();
} 

public long insert(String content1, String content2, String content3,
                String content4, String content5, String content6, 
                           String content7, String content8){

 ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT1, content1);
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT2, content2);  
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT3, content3);  
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT4, content4);  
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT5, content5);  
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT6, content6);  
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT7, content7);
 contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT8, content8);

 return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
} 

public int deleteAll(){
 return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}
public Cursor queueAll(){
 String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2, KEY_CONTENT3,
                              KEY_CONTENT4, KEY_CONTENT5, KEY_CONTENT6, 
                                        KEY_CONTENT7, KEY_CONTENT8};

 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
 null, null, null, null, null, null);
   return cursor;

} 

 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
CursorFactory factory, int version) {
super(context, name, factory, version);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    }

  } 

}
```

So this just basically stores a bunch of information in a table that is loaded with a cursor into a listview. If anyone can help me with my OnItemClickListener or with grouping the column items together, that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to set a new listadaper limiting the results to everything with `ABC`

for example:

```
Cursor c = sqlLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE,
new String[] {KEY_ID,COLUMN_Y},
COLUMN_X + "=" + ITEM_IN_COLUMN_X_CLICKED,
null,null,null);
```

the key is the `where` in the query, you want to query all items with the item clicked ie. `COLUMN_X + "=" + ITEM_IN_COLUMN_X_CLICKED`.

so if you clicked `ABC` the new list would bring up everything in `column y` with `ABC` in `column x`

Comment: This works thank you, I just need a way to group similar column items now!